# Where to ask a question about rocket fuel?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question about rocket fuel, and I'm wondering if I should do it here or on chemistry. It would be about an alternative to certain fuels. Where should I ask this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's not about making or storing fuel at home, it would be welcome here. We have had questions about alternative fuels before, for example:

[How would the Saturn V have differed if the first stage was using liquid methane and LOX?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17684/58)